# Why is there a PatternSyntax Excpetion for the following program?

Tags: java, regex, exception

I am getting a Pattern Syntax Exception for the following program. I have escaped the backslashes by using `"\\"`, but there is a still an exception saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 1
\left(
```

^

Here is the code:

```
String[] paren = {"\\big(","\\Big(","\\bigg(","\\Bigg(","\\left("};
for(String x : paren){
    if(line.contains(x))
        line=line.replaceAll(x, "("); //error on this line
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try escaping your `(` in `paren`'s values. The `String#replaceAll` method passes its first argument through a regex pattern compiler, and `(` has a special regex meaning for grouping, but also expects a closing `)` that your `paren` values don't have.

Answer (score 2):

`\l` is an invalid escape sequence and you have unescaped `(`.

Note that if you want to match a literal backslash, you need to double escape it, and then escape those again because it all resides inside a string literal. That is why `"\\l"` is being parsed as the regex pattern `\l` (which is an invalid escape sequence). And `"\\b"` and `"\\B"` are parsed as the escape sequences `\b` and `\B` which are word- and non-word boundaries.

Assuming you would like to match the literal backslash, try this instead:

```
{"\\\\big\\(","\\\\Big\\(","\\\\bigg\\(","\\\\Bigg\\(","\\\\left\\("};
```

but then, your `contains(...)` call won't work anymore!

Or perhaps better/safer, let `Pattern` quote/escape your input properly:

```
String[] paren = {"\\big(","\\Big(","\\bigg(","\\Bigg(","\\left("};

for(String x : paren){

    if(line.contains(x)) {

        line = line.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(x), "(");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to replace each of literals `"\\big("`, `"\\Big("`, `"\\bigg("`, `"\\Bigg("`, `"\\left("` then avoid using `replaceAll` because it uses regex as first argument representing value which should be replaced. In your case strings you want to replace contain regex metacharacters like `(` or anchors like `\\b` `\\B` so even if this would not throw Exception you would not get results you wanted.

Instead use `replace` (without `All` suffix) method which will automatically escape all regex metacharacters, so you will avoid problems like unescaped `(`.

So try with

```
String[] paren = {"\\big(","\\Big(","\\bigg(","\\Bigg(","\\left("};
for(String x : paren){
    if(line.contains(x))
        line=line.replace(x, "("); 
}
```